# SqlDataAdapter.Fill is very slow with multiple result set

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core-2.0

In my stored procedure, I am returning 13 tables. In management studio, proc is taking around 150ms-250ms to execute which is fine.
In my asp.net core (c#) project, I filled the dataset with that procedure and here it takes more than 20 seconds or sometimes 35+ seconds to fill dataset via sqldataadapter.
Can anyone please help me optimize this, so that data can be filled quickly.
Below is the code

**Stored Procedure**
[image]

**C# Code**
[image]

**Update:** I tried SqlDataAdapter with Add instead AddWithValue but result is same. No improvement at all.
[image]

Comment: You might want to rethink your approach and try not to load 13 tables in the dataset. It is not clear what you are trying to do with 13 tables in dataset it is difficult to suggest any improvement approach.

Comment: you are using a transaction in c # code?

Comment: It's a trading application and all that data is required. Cannot skip any table. And no transaction anywhere. @Xilmiki

Comment: try adding MultipleActiveResultSets=True;  in connection string.

Comment: It's already set to true. @Xilmiki

Comment: [`AddWithValue` isn't helping the situation.](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) You might get a slight performance boost if you set parameter db types appropriately.

Comment: If the data is read only then it would be much faster to use a SqlDataReader into a strongly typed collection than to incur all the overhead of adapters and data tables.

Comment: let me try this and revert back @Crowcoder

Comment: @Crowcoder I tried that approach but result is same. I added in my question, please check update section. I added screenshot also.

Comment: I did say you "might" get a "slight" boost. And you probably did, just not enough to notice. Again, a reader would be more efficient if you don't need the change tracking features of data sets

Comment: After running the query fetch the session wait stats into and print them out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Maybe  this link [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) can help you

Comment: Reading this article @GuidoG